# iOS predicate for searching each word in a string of an array

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, predicate

I have an array and I want to implement autocomplete with it. The autocomplete should work in such a way that for eg:

I am searching a string pi

It should return the string **big pizza** as pi is the start of the 2nd word. I have implemented :

```
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stationName CONTAINS[cd] %@", substring];
```

This is returning me all strings which have the string as a part of it. I want string which have the string present at the start of any word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `MATCHES` operator (which uses [ICU's Regular Expressions](http://icu.sourceforge.net/userguide/regexp.html)) to match against an expression which encodes all of your rules.